# Need to edit html content after accessing it within/via react.js component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

In my react project, I am loading html from src attribute within iframe, inside one of my component like this:

```
const fileUrl = `${gamesFolderUrl}/games/${urlData.game}/gameExternalAssets/gameRulesHTMLs/${lang}_help.html`;

return (
    <Modal open={open} background=''>
        <div style={{ height: popupHeight, top: headerDimension?.bottom }} className='w-[90%] flex flex-col justify-center items-center  md:w-[76%] border-[3px] border-r-[1px] border-white bg-black/90 absolute'>
        <button onClick={handleClose} className='absolute z-10 group text-white w-14 h-14 rounded-full right-2 flex justify-center items-center  -top-[0px] translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 cursor-default'>
                <img  className={`absolute h-full w-full ${visible === 'normal' ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}`} src={'./assets/images/icons/buttons/settingPanel/btn_close_normal.png'} alt={'Close'} useMap="#normal" />
                <img className={`absolute h-full w-full ${visible === 'hover' ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}`} src={'./assets/images/icons/buttons/settingPanel/btn_close_over.png'} alt={'Close'} useMap="#hover" />
                <img className={`absolute h-full w-full ${visible === 'press' ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}`}  src={'./assets/images/icons/buttons/settingPanel/btn_close_press.png'} alt={'Close'} useMap="#press" />
                <map id="normal" name="normal">
                    <area onMouseEnter={() => setVisible('hover')} style={{  cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 100 }} shape="circle" coords="28, 28, 20" alt="test" />
                </map>
                <map id="hover" name="hover">
                    <area onMouseLeave={() => setVisible('normal')} onMouseDown={() => setVisible('press')} style={{  cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 100 }} shape="circle" coords="28, 28, 20" alt="test" />
                </map>
                <map id="press" name="press">
                    <area onMouseUp={() => setVisible('hover')} style={{  cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 100 }} shape="circle" coords="28, 28, 20" alt="test" />
                </map>
            </button>
            <div className='h-[25px] w-10'>
                {/* this is a dummy div to make scrollbar spaced from top */}
            </div>
            {isHelpLoading && <img alt='loading1' className='absolute' src='./assets/images/loading/loading1.svg' />}
            <iframe onLoad={updateIframeUI} id='HELP_IFRAME' title='help' className='w-full h-full styled-scrollbar' src={fileUrl}></iframe>
        </div>
    </Modal>
)
```

Now I need to edit the following part from the content of this *${lang}_help.html* html dynamically:

```
            <div>
                <h3>RTP AS PER THE JURISDICTION</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>The return to player of the game is 95% </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

such that 95% part is dynamic, ie let's say I get the value 95 as number or "95%" as string inside variable called **"toApply"** in this component, then how'd I make this dynamic, sort of like:

```
            <div>
                <h3>RTP AS PER THE JURISDICTION</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>The return to player of the game is <DYNAMIC VALUE HERE (toApply variable)> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```